# Can I Add an Array to PortfolioJS to Use More Galleries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, touch, swipe

I used PortfolioJS.com for horizontal photography galleries on my website [meetAnthony.com](http://meetanthony.com).

The galleries work on my iMac, but not on iPhones, iPads, and other devices.

Strangely, the first gallery worked on a phone.  You could swipe with one finger to see photos to the end of the gallery.

**THE PROBLEM**

Galleries 2-6 didn't swipe on mobile devices.  After a few moments, I could swipe the images with two fingers.  But it took a few minutes.

I want the Photography galleries to scroll on the computer and swipe (one finger) on mobile devices.

**THE SOLUTION?**

I think the PortfolioJS JavaScript was using the id "#gallery".  I think the JavaScript did not support all six galleries when I added more id's (#gallery-2, #gallery-3, etc.).

So I changed the first gallery from id "#gallery" to "#gallery-1".  I used "var gallery" to create an array with all six gallery id's.  I don't know if this works yet.  I don't have an iPhone, iPad, or mobile device.

**INCLUDED IN HEAD:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = $("#gallery-1, #gallery-2, #gallery-3, #gallery-4, #gallery-5, #gallery-6").portfolio({
        logger: true,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        height: "540px",
        width: "100%",
        enableKeyboardNavigation: false,
        lightbox: false,
        showArrows: false

    });
    p.init();
});
</script>
```

**INCLUDED IN LINKED JS:**

```
// Local variables
var gallery = new Array("#gallery-1", "#gallery-2", "#gallery-3", "#gallery-4", "#gallery-5", "#gallery-6");

var portfolio = this, gallery = this
```

http://meetanthony.com/script/portfolio.js
meetanthony.com/script/portfolio.pack.min.js

Can someone let me know if adding an array to PortfolioJS is the answer?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use one portfolio with multiple galleries with something like this

```
<section class="wrapper" >
  <div id="gallery">....</div>                                                                          
  <div id="gallery1" style="display:none">.....</div>
  <div id="gallery2" style="display:none">.....</div>
  <div id="gallery3" style="display:none">.....</div>
  <div id="gallery4" style="display:none">.....</div>
</section>
```

then in script

```
 $("#gallery").html($('#gallery1').html()) //for instance

 var p = $("#gallery").portfolio();
 p.init();
```